# Getting Rid of Unwanted Text in SQL Server 2005 Database

Tags: sql-server, replace

I hope someone can help.  My database was infected by a virus which inserted a string of characters into virtually every text and varchar field.

- Before the virus, data was stored like "San Diego Football Team".
- After the virus, data reads like "San Diego Football Team - plus a string of HTML characters, style sheet content, url's, etc."

I can't include what the tags are because they will not be rendered in this message.

To complicate matters, the additional information is random strings of HTML tags (w/data) so it's difficult to identify patterns.  Luckily, all of the inserted text starts with the title tag (w/brackets).  Any suggestions for to remove this text easily?  We have roughly 500k records.

Many thanks for your help.

Jim

Comment: This would almost certainly be a SQL injection vulnerability in your application not a virus. By the way to include HTML tags in your question just format them as code.

Comment: You said it started with the title tag, does it end with a close title tag?  And are any of your text columns supposed to have HTML or title tags in them?

Comment: How about restoring a backup of this database?  Just a thought.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get rid of appended text

```
update @table set
  firstname = SUBSTRING(firstname, 0, CHARINDEX('<title', firstname,  0))
Where
  CHARINDEX('<title', firstname,  0) > 0
```

This is assuming the text is at the end of actual original text. Try this with a column first and extend it to other columns.

Use this with caution!